# Pygame Drawing (For Easter)

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering how to draw a cloud on pygame. The only thing I know how to do is regular circles and ellipses. Also, please tell me how to draw a bunny or some cute animals, my assignment is to make a Easter themed picture on pygame. Thank you. uwu.

Answer (score 1):

While you can manually draw lines in pygame using `pygame.draw.line` and even single pixels if you draw a line with a length and width of one, I would recommend simply downloading an image and displaying it. This is very easy in pygame. Say I have an image "cloud.png":

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
cloud_img = pygame.image.load("cloud.png")
# You can also easily resize images:
cloud_img = pygame.transform.smoothscale(cloud_img, (500, 500))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
# Now just blit image to screen:
screen.blit(cloud_img, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass  # Just keep program running unil user exits
```